# Randomization of a class object inside a class in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
class c2;
  rand bit[1:0] a;
  rand bit[1:0] b;

  function void my_print();
    $display("a = %b", a);
    $display("b = %b", b);
  endfunction   
endclass

class c1;
  rand bit[1:0] i;
  rand bit[1:0] j;
  rand c2 o2;

  function new();
    o2 = new();
  endfunction

  function void my_print();
    $display("i = %b", i);
    $display("j = %b", j);
  endfunction
endclass

program p1;   
  c1 o1 = new;
  c2 o2_local = new;

  initial begin
  if (o1.randomize() with {o2 == o2_local;}) begin
    o1.my_print();
    o2.my_print();
  end
endprogram
```

In this program, randomization is getting failed for o1.randomize(). If I take individual variables for o2 and use inline constraint with that (like o2.a == o2_local.a), then it works.

Is there any alternative way to do this type of randomization, as my original class contains almost 38 variable, and individual assignments would be troublesome.

Comment: 'Nested class' isn't the proper terminology here. A nested class is a class defined within another class. What you have there is an object member of another class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` operator when applied to object doesn't do what you think it does. It only compares the handles. The solver is failing because it sees that `o1.o2` and `o2_local` are different objects and thus aren't "equal".

If `o2_local` isn't supposed to be changed by the randomization then you can just do the following:

```
o1.o2 = o2_local;
o1.o2.rand_mode(0);
if (o1.randomize()) begin
  o1.print();
  o1.o2.print();
end
o1.o2.rand_mode(1);
```

This way you've assigned `o2_local` to `o2` and if you were to have any constraints that referenced fields of `o2` and of `o1` they would be solved.

The problem with object equivalence is symptomatic to all OOP languages. You'd need a function that takes all fields of the object into account to determine if two objects are equal:

```
class c2;
  // ...

  function bit equals(c2 obj);
    return a == obj.a && b == obj.b;
  endfunction
endclass
```

This function works fine in procedural code, but it won't help you for randomization as using functions in constraints is trickier.

An ugly solution would also be to declare a macro that expands to the body of the `equals(...)` function, because having the `==` statements unrolled will work in a constraint.

Comment: Yes I have tried this solution, but one problem is that, after doing o1.o2.rand_mode(0), it won't randomize o2. But if any constraints are present in class c2, then those constraints won't get solved either.

Comment: That's exactly what I said. But why would you want to randomize `o2` too? From the example you gave it seems that you have an externally randomize object of type `c2` and you just want the `o2` field to contain the same values.

Comment: Yes it seems convincing. Thanks a lot for answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all the variables in the c2 class needs to be randomized "with" did not have much impact since "with" is used to constrain only certain values, A simple method would do all variable randomization, I doubt because of this reason LRM doesn't talk much about inline constraints of nested classes

```
 initial begin
  if (o1.randomize()) begin
     if (o2_local.randomize()) begin
       o1.my_print();
       o2_local.my_print();
     end
  end
  else $fatal ("Randomize failed");
  end
endprogram
```

As you have figured how to constraint each variable, this would help in if only specific values are to be constrained inline.

Comment: @Emmam : I want o2 of o1 to have values of o2_local, because original data is in o2, and o2_local is just to give data to o2. So I cant use your code, as it won't do o2 = o2_local